# How do I move my arrow keys in a square until I stop it in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, roblox

I'm trying to move my arrow keys in a square in Roblox, but I need help with coding an AutoHotkey script to do that. My goal is:

1. Start moving in a square
2. Stop it when I press the hotkey again

Any suggestions?

I tried using Tinytask, but that didn't work, because you have to get it perfectly aligned. I also searched Google for about 30 minutes looking for information, but I found nothing that I was looking for.